# What is the frequency spectrum of an "instantaneous" excitation force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, acoustics, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

Suppose you have a brass rod and it gets excited by an (almost) instantaneous force, for example by a hammer hit. Now, this force is acted upon the rod for a specific amount of time, let's call it Δt. If we think that we can write the fourier series of this force, I can understand that it will be the sum of many periodic excitation forces with many different frequencies.
However, I read something even more specific: that the frequencies will be continuously distributed between 0-vmax=1/Δt, and the force's amplitude will be decreasing function of the frequency. I don't understand why vmax would be this nor why the amplitude's distribution would be like this and I don't know how to prove them. Any ideas?

[image: If force F=Focos(2πt/v), Fo=Fo(v) is decreasing]

Answer (score 2):

For non periodic, compact time signal, you need to perform Fourier transform instead of Fourier series, namely

$\mathscr{F}\{u(t)\}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u(t) e^{-i \omega t} dt$.

You can qualitatively interpret it as the continuous limit of the Fourier series for a non-periodic (or infinite-period) function.

If you have:

- an impulsive signal $u(t) = \delta(t)$ the transform reads $U(\omega) = 1$
- a step signal $u(t) = 1$ for $t \in [0,T]$ the tranform reads $U(\omega) = \dfrac{1}{i \omega} \left[ 1 - e^{-i \omega T}\right]$

Comment: okay, this answers my question, thanks a lot, it was easier than i expected

Comment: actually, making the graph of the real part of this, i can see that the force=0 for the first time for v=1/2Δt, so it doesnt look like the force's distribution is decreasing until vmax=1/Δt.
Also, i can't see from which point we derive that vmax will have this value. It would make sense if vmax is the first value for which F(v)=0, although still i wouldn't be persuaded on why to take only those first frequencies, when there is a non zero force in other areas too. But now that even this isn't true i don't know what im missing.     
The book where i read that vmax=1/Δt had an ~=,to be precise.

Comment: Usually the frequency response is plotted as the magnitude against the frequency, and the phase against the frequency, like in Bode diagrams, since magnitude and phase have physical meanings that are easier to interpret. As you can see from the function, the module only tends to zero as the frequency tends to infinity. But since you can't measure under the sensitivity of your instruments, you can think at that threshold as approximately zero.